# Users set passwords but cannot login

Tags: users, password, activation

I'm working on a WP-based site that requires creating accounts for users and sending them their password reset links by email so they can activate their accounts. 
After manually sending out all the emails, the users set their passwords with no error but they cannot log in to the site.

This is my code:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-load.php');
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php';

$recepients = get_users( 'blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=test' ); //Retrieves users of specific role

foreach ( $recepients as $user ) {

    $key = wp_generate_password( 20, false );
    do_action( 'retrieve_password_key', $user->user_login, $key );

    $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );
    $hashed = time() . ':' . $wp_hasher->HashPassword( $key );

    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->users, array( 'user_activation_key' => $hashed ), array( 'user_login' => $user->user_login ) );

    if ( apply_filters( 'send_new_user_notification', true ) ) {
        $message = 'A new account has been created for you. Please click the following link: <a href="http://www.mysite.gr/activation/?key='.$key.'&login='.$user->user_login.'">ACTIVATE YOUR ACCOUNT</a>'; 
        $title = sprintf( '%s - Your account activation', wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES ) );
        $title = apply_filters( 'new_user_notification_title', $title, $user_id );
        $message = apply_filters( 'new_user_notification_message', $message, $key, $user_id );

        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
            'From: ME <me@test.com>',               
        );
        $send_message = wp_mail( $user->user_email, $title, $message, $headers );
    }
}
```

I'm using WP v4.3.1 a number of plugins for keeping all the user interaction on the front-end (I dont want them logging into their profiles).

One idea I have is to perhaps update the user_activation_key field in wp_users table based on the key that has already been sent so that I wont have to re-send the activation email twice. Is this *at all* posible? I mean is there a way to 'fix' the user_activation_key in the DB by *somehow* using the keys already sent to the users?

ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you create the users? How the users set their passwords? Why a user can not log in, because the password is not correct or because the account is not correctly activated?

Comment: I create the users in the backend but I have deactivated the default email notification so that I can send it in a different format including more information. The email above is a small segment of the actual content.